# How to set a counter with Hector / Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, hector

I should want use a counter with hector for cassandra. I copy/paste [this test case from test code](https://github.com/rantav/hector/blob/master/core/src/test/java/me/prettyprint/cassandra/model/MutatorTest.java#L214) from hector :

```
    Mutator<String> m = createMutator(keyspace, se);
    MutationResult mr = m.insertCounter( // exception here.
     "k", "Counter1", createCounterColumn("name", 5)); 
    assertTrue("Execution time on single counter insert should be > 0", mr.getExecutionTimeMicro() > 0);
    assertTrue("Should have operated on a host", mr.getHostUsed() != null);
    CounterQuery<String, String> counter = new ThriftCounterColumnQuery<String,String>(keyspace, se, se);
    counter.setColumnFamily("Counter1").setKey("k").setName("name");
    assertEquals(new Long(5), counter.execute().get().getValue());
```

But I get this exception, on *insertCounter* line, because Counter1 is unconfigured, he says :

```
me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HInvalidRequestException: InvalidRequestException(why:unconfigured columnfamily Counter1)
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.service.ExceptionsTranslatorImpl.translate(ExceptionsTranslatorImpl.java:45) ~[hector-core-1.0-5.jar:na]
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.connection.HConnectionManager.operateWithFailover(HConnectionManager.java:264) ~[hector-core-1.0-5.jar:na]
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.ExecutingKeyspace.doExecuteOperation(ExecutingKeyspace.java:97) ~[hector-core-1.0-5.jar:na]
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.MutatorImpl.execute(MutatorImpl.java:243) ~[hector-core-1.0-5.jar:na]
    at me.prettyprint.cassandra.model.MutatorImpl.insertCounter(MutatorImpl.java:285) ~[hector-core-1.0-5.jar:na]
```

OK, but the test case doesn't configure Counter1 ? How I configure that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create your column family on your Cassandra server.  One common way is to use the cqlsh tool.

```
cqlsh

USE Keyspace1;
CREATE COLUMNFAMILY counter1 (example text PRIMARY KEY) 
  WITH comparator=text and default_validation=counter;
```

In Hector, you could use the ColumnFamilyDefinition class-- something like this:

```
    ColumnFamilyDefinition cfDef = HFactory.createColumnFamilyDefinition(KEYSPACE, "counter1");
    cfDef.setKeyValidationClass(ComparatorType.UTF8TYPE.getClassName());
    cfDef.setComparatorType(ComparatorType.UTF8TYPE);
    cfDef.setDefaultValidationClass(ComparatorType.COUNTERTYPE.getClassName());
    cfDef.setColumnType(ColumnType.STANDARD);
    List<ColumnFamilyDefinition> columnFamilies = new ArrayList<ColumnFamilyDefinition>();
    columnFamilies.add(cfDef);
    KeyspaceDefinition ksdef = HFactory.createKeyspaceDefinition(KEYSPACE, "org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleStrategy", 1,
            columnFamilies);
    cluster.addKeyspace(ksdef);
```

Comment: Thanks phatfingers, but I should want make all my stuff with code, with hector. Is it possible to create a column family with hector ?

Comment: Also, you might take a quick peek at a third alternative-- running CQL from your app: https://github.com/jsevellec/cassandra-unit/blob/master/src/test/java/org/cassandraunit/DataLoaderAndCQLExecutionTest.java

Comment: to phatfingers : thanks; but if I do that I get `me.prettyprint.hector.api.exceptions.HInvalidRequestException: InvalidRequestException(why:CounterColumnType is not a valid comparator)` on line `cluster.addColumnFamily(cfDef);` !

Comment: I first tested, then added a new version.

Comment: OK it's work, Thanks ! But it's a little difficult to understand for a beginner.